# Constructing a List<T> from an Enum

Tags: java, collections

What it comes down to is I'm attempting to construct a `List<T>` from the `java.util.List` package based on an enumerator, but here's the catch- I don't want the first value to be in the list. The way that I've come up with doing this... Well... It can't be a good thing.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()).remove(0));
```

This effectively creates a List<> from my enum, and removes the first value, then tries to create another list with the created list.

This may actually be the correct way to do it, but just looking at it is screaming "Inefficient". I showed it to a few people on a forum that I'm a member of and they all said how ugly it was, and laughed; However not a single one of them could/would provide a better way to go about doing it.

Comment: Why do you create the list again when you already have a list?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel because the list returned by Arrays.asList() does not support the remove() method.

Comment: The reasining for this is because I couldn't figure out how to return the list after using the remove() function, I'm trying to do this all in a single-line return. I should have probably stated that. #remove returns the value that was removed, so I'm having a problem figuring out how to go about this in a single-line path.

Comment: Try `ArrayList<MyEnum> list;
  (list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()))).remove(0);`

Comment: Well it's sort of pointless to ask why something is inefficient when you make it deliberately inefficient just so it would fit on one line. `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()); list.remove(0); return list;` would be easier to read and more efficient.

Comment: mais jean-baptiste , les deux Arrays.asList() envoie le meme type de list : List<T>

Comment: Use two lines, and wrap these two lines in a method. You'll have to create a copy of Arrays.asList() in order to remove its first element, though.

Comment: @indian read the javadoc of Arrays.asList(): *Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array*. So, trying to call remove() on this list will throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: It should not work because Arrays.asList() returns Arrays inner class that do not support remove().

Comment: @JBNizet  mmmm i just did https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Collections.unmodifiableList() also returns a plain List. Would it be unmodifiable if remove() did effectively remove an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that code is really ugly or inefficient. The bigger problem is it doesn't work because the list returned by [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is backed by the underlying array, and so it has a fixed size.

You can use [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) instead of `remove` to get it working:

```
List<MyEnum> list = Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values());
list = list.subList(1, list.size());
```

This means that the resulting list actually consists of two list objects (the `asList` and its `subList`), which may or may not bother you. However, you can create a flat `ArrayList` from the resulting list:

```
list = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

If you'd rather minimize object allocation, loop the values and add them to a single list directly:

```
MyEnum[] values = MyEnum.values();
List<MyEnum> list = new ArrayList<>(values.length - 1);
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
    list.add(values[i]);
```

Comment: What would be the performance comparison vs `ArrayList<SlayerTask> list;
   (list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(SlayerTask.values()))).remove(0);`

Comment: @Christian.tucker removing the first element of an arraylist forces the list to copy all the elements toward the left. Not that it would make a big difference, but the above code woud be faster.

Comment: @Christian.tucker The for-loop that adds items to a single list would be faster, as it avoids shoving the items around with the `remove` call. It's a small difference though. I wonder why you're so worried about the performance of this? If the resulting list is not being modified later, you can create it just once and keep it around. If it needs to be modified, you can create the list once as a template, and then create copies of it with `new ArrayList<>(template)`. If every nanosecond *really* matters, you should be using bare arrays rather than Lists.

Comment: @Boann - It's not so much about me being concerned with the performance, as it is wanting to learn how to do things efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
  Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()).subList(1, MyEnum.values().length);
```

Comment: Indeed; Easily the simpelest and clearest.  Downside is the first element will not be collected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can't (wouldn't want to) use MyEnum.values and treat your first element differently where it's used?

```
public enum Enums {

    first,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f;

    public boolean isFirst(Enums e) {
        return e == first;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that method shouldn't be static? Or remove the parameter: `public boolean isFirst() { return this == first }`

Answer (score -1):

This would work:

```
List<T> enums = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(MyEnum.values(), 1, MyEnum.values().length - 1));
```

Or java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).collect(Collectors.toList()).subList(1, MyEnum.values() - 1);
```

Hmmm... not much better .

Comment: Still incorrect. The last argument should be MyEnum.values().length (it's exclusive). And it shouldn't call values() twice: each call returns a new array.

Comment: @jbn Doh! I was thinking it was length, not index. BTW, not an excuse, but I rarely have a compiler handy - I thumb code in on my phone, so I have to remember all the APIs, or browse for the javadoc if I have time. Still, thanks for picking it up. The double call to values() is to keep it one line.